# When I import project to Android Studio it only sees gradle module

Tags: android, android-studio

Here's the [repository](https://github.com/zbysheck/SeldonAndroid).

I try to open it in my android studio, but it doesn't seem to work. I can open it but I don't see dource, only gradle project.

Can be important: I use Android Studio 1.0

Comment: Why are you using an outdated version of Android Studio?

Comment: You should be using Android Studio 2.1 - If the project has a gradle version to new then Android Studio may not be able to open the project correctly.

Comment: Update your android studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try click Tools -> Android -> SDK MANAGER -> Update -> Check Now. If this not work just use google with "android studio donwload" and download it